# SAS: Substring TIme in SAS after 10 length

Tags: sas, format, string-length

I try to substring time  the following way:

```
HH = substrn(Time,1,2); MM = substrn(Time,4,2); SS = substrn(Time,7,2); MSS = substrn(Time,10,3);
```

However, SAS doesn't see the last part (MSS) which should be the last 3 digits, i.e. the milliseconds. The time variable is formatted as time20.3. and shows a length of 8. 
I believe it is the lenght's fault but how do I increase it to 10? I only know how it works for non-numeric variables.

Best, M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If TIME has format TIME20.3 then it is a numeric variable. A storage length of 10 is impossible for numeric variables since SAS stores all numbers as as 64-bit floating point.

Just use functions to get parts.

```
 hour = hour(time);
 minute = minute(time);
 second = second(time);
 milliseconds = 1000*(time - int(time) );
```

If you don't convert it to character yourself then SAS will automatically convert it using BEST12. format instead.  So instead of a value like `'09:26:47.543'` you will see a value like `'34007.542699'`.

You could use `VVALUE()` function to see the formatted value or the `PUT()` function.